# Azure API Manager increased response time when function scales

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-api-management

After doing some load testing with a an azure function on the consumption plan that scales I ran into an interesting scenario. Right now I have a function app that is expecting an http post behind an api management instance. The function app does some processing and returns a response to the caller. The API manager has no caching for the time being since we are expecting the process to just pass through the body through for processing.

When I call the function directly, the app will scale appropriately and I see SOME cold start behavior from the function app, but the average response time is sub 200 ms from a local request to azure for a sustained load.

When I call the function through the api manager and have a sustained load on the instance I start seeing 30-60 second response times around the 5 minute mark of the load test.

The load is 2 requests per second and fully asynchronous so there is no blocking. Additionally, there are no database calls, this is solely a compute function.

Has anyone else seen this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a setting or LB problem. What you can do is reduce the functionTimeout setting in your host.json (e.g. 20 seconds) and then, add a retry policy on API Management.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-advanced-policies#example-7

Comment: Thank you, I knew it was something simple!